# Manual linking to Windows library in LLVM

Tags: windows, linker, llvm

I'm writing my own programming language, and am wanting to compile it to native binaries by compiling to LLVM IR, then letting the rest of the LLVM toolchain take over. Eventually, I will target multiple platforms, but for now I'm just focusing on Windows.

For starters, I have the empty program compiling, which implies that in general my toolchain is set up and working, and I get a no op executable out of it. The next logical step is doing "Hello World", but after looking at the LLVM IR output of clang of the C program that simply calls `puts("Hello World!")` it looks like a slightly easier first step is to simply `_exit();`. When reviewing the clang output of that C program, it looks like the relevant line is to do `call void @_exit(i32 0)`. I've distilled it down to what I think is the bare minimum program which calls exit:

```
define i64* @main() {
    %1 = alloca i32, align 4
    store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
    call void @_exit(i32 0)
    unreachable
}
declare dso_local void @_exit(i32)
```

When trying to run the equivalent C program directly, of course it works when I use `clang` directly, but the steps after creation of the LLVM IR are opaque to me, and I believe I'm using the wrong linker options or something, as I get `lld-link: error: undefined symbol: _exit` during the lld-link step. (Actually, this also occurs when I try to manually link the output of `clang -S --emit-llvm`, so I have no reason to believe my IR is the problem). The current invocation I'm using for lld-link is `lld-link /out:"exit.exe" /entry:main exit.obj`. I've tried playing around with adding various flavors of the `/defaultlib` switch, including manually linking to libcmt both libucrt which I do believe contain _exit after looking through the symbols with `dumpbin`, but that doesn't seem to help. Looking at the IR output of the clang program, it doesn't seem like there's any particular reference to <stdlib.h>, so I guess that information is lost after the IR generation stage, so I don't think I'm missing anything in my IR.

This appears to be a general Windows linker problem, rather than anything to do with LLVM, since if I do `link /out:exit.exe /entry:main exit.obj` I get basically the same error.

Anyways, there's clearly some step here during the linking that I don't understand, around how to find the actual library that a given external call lives in, so if anyone could point me in the right direction of how to figure this out for any given C runtime call, that would be great. Particularly in this case, I guess I need to find the library which contains the _exit function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the libcmt has been replaced. The replacement is ucrt, and so doing /defaultlib:ucrt seems to fix the problem!